# how can I dump certain tables

Tags: mysql

I only want to dump the tables which begin with 'JI' et 'QRTZ' 
I searched in strackoverflow, the way to do this is using --ignore-table, but i have hundreds tables to ignore...

any tools to get this job done?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a script to do this.

For example, create a PHP script that queries for all the tables in the database and then creates a .bat/.sh file that you can run to do your job.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way:

```
mysql databasename -u [username] -p[password] -e 'show tables like "JI%" and "QRTZ%"' | grep -v Tables_in | xargs mysqldump [dbname] -u [username] -p[password] > [dump_file]
```